# Skype For Buisness Auto-Reply Add-in Suggestions

Tags: skype, automation, bots, reply

Are there any decent Skype Add-ins or a feature in Skype that I can set up an auto-reply for incoming chats?

I looked at Pamela For Skype, but it didn't work and checked for features built within Skype and I also tried adding someone as a favorite and seeing if there was an auto-reply feature, but did not see anything.

Comment: What type of auto-reply? In skype for business everyone already sees your status, and location and you can change both of them at will. It should be fairly obvious if you are “away for 2 hours” or “offline” that someone should email you instead at which point you can add an auto-reply if necessary. This just doesn’t seem like a feature with much use. The “auto reply” is the real-time status of your availability. Skype is an instant messaging app, not an email app.

Comment: Looking for something that will reply to incoming messages to tell someone to call my business number instead of chat my via Skype.

Comment: I guess I’m not seeing the issue here. We use Skype for business throughout our organization. It’s obvious that someone is not available via Skype because it literally says not available, or away. If someone insists on sending someone that is “away” or “unavailable” a message via Skype, that is kind of silly. The obvious thing to do is send an email or pick up the phone. If your organization is configured properly users have all your contact information already by searching the Outlook address book.